# optimize an inner join between two multi-million row tables

Tags: performance, postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

I'm new to Postgres and even newer to understanding how explain works. I have a query below which is typical, I just replace the date:

```
explain
select account_id, 
   security_id, 
   market_value_date, 
   sum(market_value) market_value
from market_value_history mvh
inner join holding_cust hc on hc.id = mvh.owning_object_id
where
hc.account_id = 24766
and market_value_date = '2015-07-02'
and mvh.created_by = 'HoldingLoad'
group by account_id, security_id, market_value_date
order by security_id, market_value_date;
```

Attached is a screenshot of explain
[image]
The count for holding_cust table is 2 million rows and market_value_history table has 163 million rows

Below are the table definitions and indexes for market_value_history and holding_cust:

I'd appreciate any advice you may be able to give me on tuning this query.

```
CREATE TABLE public.market_value_history
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('market_value_id_seq'::regclass),
  market_value numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
  market_value_date date,
  holding_type character varying(25) NOT NULL,
  owning_object_type character varying(25) NOT NULL,
  owning_object_id integer NOT NULL,
  created_by character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  created_dt timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  last_modified_dt timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT market_value_history_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.market_value_history
  OWNER TO postgres;

-- Index: public.ix_market_value_history_id

-- DROP INDEX public.ix_market_value_history_id;

CREATE INDEX ix_market_value_history_id
  ON public.market_value_history
  USING btree
  (owning_object_type COLLATE pg_catalog."default", owning_object_id);

-- Index: public.ix_market_value_history_object_type_date

-- DROP INDEX public.ix_market_value_history_object_type_date;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_market_value_history_object_type_date
  ON public.market_value_history
  USING btree
  (owning_object_type COLLATE pg_catalog."default", owning_object_id, holding_type COLLATE pg_catalog."default", market_value_date);




CREATE TABLE public.holding_cust
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('holding_cust_id_seq'::regclass),
  account_id integer NOT NULL,
  security_id integer NOT NULL,
  subaccount_type integer,
  trade_date date,
  purchase_date date,
  quantity numeric(18,6),
  net_cost numeric(18,2),
  adjusted_net_cost numeric(18,2),
  open_date date,
  close_date date,
  created_by character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  created_dt timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  last_modified_dt timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT holding_cust_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.holding_cust
  OWNER TO postgres;

-- Index: public.ix_holding_cust_account_id

-- DROP INDEX public.ix_holding_cust_account_id;

CREATE INDEX ix_holding_cust_account_id
  ON public.holding_cust
  USING btree
  (account_id);

-- Index: public.ix_holding_cust_acctid_secid_asofdt

-- DROP INDEX public.ix_holding_cust_acctid_secid_asofdt;

CREATE INDEX ix_holding_cust_acctid_secid_asofdt
  ON public.holding_cust
  USING btree
  (account_id, security_id, trade_date DESC);

-- Index: public.ix_holding_cust_security_id

-- DROP INDEX public.ix_holding_cust_security_id;

CREATE INDEX ix_holding_cust_security_id
  ON public.holding_cust
  USING btree
  (security_id);

-- Index: public.ix_holding_cust_trade_date

-- DROP INDEX public.ix_holding_cust_trade_date;

CREATE INDEX ix_holding_cust_trade_date
  ON public.holding_cust
  USING btree
  (trade_date);
```

Comment: it would be great to see `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE`, but it looks like you're getting sequence scan for `market_value_date` AND `created_by` condition; it may be appropriate to create **B-tree** multicolumn index for these two columns in order to hit the index.

Comment: `created_by character varying(50) NOT NULL,` looks like a low cardinality column, which could be replaced by an integer FK to a persons-table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. As Dmitry pointed out, you should look at creating an Index on `market_value_date` field. Its possible that post that you have a completely different query plan, which may or may not bring up other bottlenecks, but it should certainly remove this `seq-Scan`.
2. Minor (since I doubt if it affects performance), but secondly, if you aren't enforcing field length by design, you may want to change createdby field to `TEXT`. As can be seen in the query, its trying to cast all createdby fields to `TEXT` for this query.

Comment: Thanks! Adding that index made all the difference